# how to express this collision detection bit as matrix operations?

Tags: matrix

I'm writing some code for collision detection, suppose 2 objects are represented by these 2 matrices:

```
object1 = [ [x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_max], [z_min, z_max]] 

object2 = [ [x_min, x_max], [y_min, y_max], [z_min, z_max]]
```

where the objects' respective values (x_min, x_max, etc) are different.

i want to say:

```
object1.x_min < object2.x_max and object1.x_max > object2.y_min  and
object1.y_min < object2.y_max and object1.y_max > object2.y_min  and
object1.z_min < object2.z_max and object1.z_max > object2.z_min
```

How do i express this as some kind of matrix operation?  Happy to rearrange the matrix layout as well.

Many thanks.

GOT SOMETHING WORKING

First i rearrange the matrices:

```
object1 = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]] )
object2 = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]] )
```

Then i just do this:

```
np.all(np.logical_and(object1[0] < object2[1],object1[1] > object2[0]))
```

If this looks like it can't get any better i'll remove the question tomorrow.

Comment: Are you using any specific programming language or environment like Numpy (Python), Matlab, Octave, ...?

Comment: using numpy but can read a bit of Octave as well.

Comment: I just fumbled around and got the following that works:

Comment: Rearranging it to

`object1 = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]] )
object2 = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]] )

np.all(np.logical_and(object1[0] < object2[1],object1[1] > object2[0]))`


Does this look like as good as it's gonna get?

Comment: have added this to the question.

Comment: Instead of deleting your question you can write your own answer, accept it and keep the question online for other users having the same problem.

Comment: OK will wait a bit and then do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FURTHER IMPROVEMENT

There isn't any reason (that's apparent to me) for keeping the min values ie. x_min, y_min, z_min, IN THE SAME MATRIX as the max values ie. x_max, y_max, z_max.  By separating them into their own matrices, i gain the power of storing many objects in the same matrix.

So instead of

```
object1 = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]] )
object2 = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_max, y_max, z_max]] )
```

I can have

```
objects_min = np.matrix([ [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_min, y_min, z_min], [x_min, y_min, z_min]....] )
objects_max = np.matrix([ [x_max, y_max, z_max], [x_max, y_max, z_max], [x_max, y_max, z_max]....] )
```

where each row is a different object.  So now if i have a new object that i want to compare with all these objects, the operation can be vectorized as well.

It would look something like:

```
collisions = np.all(np.logical_and(new_object_min < objects_max  , new_object_max > objects_min), axis =1)
```